# How to iterate over rows of .csv file and pass each row to a time-series analysis model?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, data-analysis

I want to write a program in python that iterate over each row of a data-matrix in a .csv file and then pass each row as an input to time-series-analysis model and the output(which is going to be a single value) of each row analysed over model will be stored in a form of column.

So far, I have tried iterating over rows, passing it through model and printing each output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
from random import random


data=pd.read_csv('EXAMPLEMATRIX.csv',header=None)
for i in data.iterrows():
    df=np.asarray(i)
    model=AR(df)
    model_fit=model.fit()
    yhat=model_fitd.predict(len(df),len(df))
    print(yhat)
```

but I get an error:

> ValueError: maxlag should be < nobs

Please help me solve this problem or finding out where it is going wrong or provide me a reference for solving this problem.

THANKS in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
from random import random

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    row = data.iloc[i]
    model=AR(row.values)
    model_fit=model.fit()
    yhat=model_fit.predict(len(row),len(row))
    print(yhat)
```

Comment: Following the suggested code gives error: 'ValueError: Prediction must have `end` after `start`'

Comment: I run this code at kaggle for 2000 columns for daily measures of something. It worked. Understand your data types and change if there is an issue. row.values gives numpy array.

Comment: another problem is how we can do this if we have large data set with some missing values Error:exog contains inf or nans